# WHERE IN () doesn't use index after upgrading MariaDB 10.2 to 10.6

Tags: mysql, mariadb

A table with more than 650,000,000 rows does not use an index after updating MariaDB from 10.2 to 10.6

```
CREATE TABLE `parts` (
  `mainid` int(10)    UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `pid`    bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name`   varchar(40) COLLATE utf8mb3_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `dt`     date                NOT NULL
) 

ALTER TABLE `parts`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`mainid`),
  ADD KEY `pid` (`pid`);
```

Maria uses an index when my queries have `WHERE pid IN ( n1 )`, but it doesn't use an index when my queries have `WHERE pid IN ( n1, n2, n3 )`.

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    *
FROM
    parts
WHERE
    pid IN (
        6826931823469672941,
        2750571406036799415,
         156705013816687978
    );
```

| MariaDB 10.2 | MariaDB 10.6 |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

---

**Curiously**, if I put the `bigint` literals in quotes it uses a better plan:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT
    *
FROM
    parts
WHERE
    pid IN (
        '6826931823469672941',
        '2750571406036799415',
         '156705013816687978'
    );
```

[image]

I tried to change `eq_range_index_dive_limit` to `0` (value in 10.2) from 200 (value in 10.6) in `my.cnf`, but it didn't help. Same with the maximum value of `4294967295`.

Comment: Post your **full query**, your **full** `CREATE TABLE` statement, and **all** `INDEX` objects (and `PRIMARY KEY` and `UNIQUE` constraints on the table), and your query's execution plan (from `EXPLAIN`).

Comment: @Dai I've updated my comment please suggest something

Comment: It's possible your index `STATISTICS` are out-of-whack - [try running `ANALYZE TABLE parts;`. Also, that article also mentions a change in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/engine-independent-table-statistics/) in **10.4** (right in-between your 10.2 update to 10.6) regarding the `use_stat_tables: preferably_for_queries` option - you should read it over.

Comment: @Dai Thank you. But "ANALYZE TABLE parts;" and use_stat_tables = "NEVER" didn't help. I guess it's just a BIGINT error, since I don't have this with INT (mainid). Can I use single quotes for BIGINT? As I understand it, it's the same if I don't use them.

Comment: Something about this is quite odd. Can you attempt an [optimizer trace](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/optimizer-trace-guide/) and write a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/).